# How to get job from ms sql server realtime?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have application on client for get job info form sql server via ODBC.

code for connection :

```
 string sqlJobQuery = "select j.job_id, j.name, j.enabled, jh.run_status, jh.message, jh.run_date, jh.step_name, jh.run_time from sysjobs j inner join sysjobhistory jh on j.job_id = jh.job_id";

       // create SQL connection and set up SQL Command for query
       using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("server=10.15.13.70;database=msdb;user id=sa;pwd="))
       using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlJobQuery, _con))
```

Is it possible if I use timer to get job info every 1s and show job info on listview.
****i want everything is realtime ****

how to do?
please..

Comment: You have asked 6 questions and you haven't accepted any answers. If you don't accept answers, people will not want to help you.

Comment: On a side note, SQL jobs can't be run (at least very easily) more than once every MINUTE ... so do you really need to check this every 1 second? That seems like overkill, 30 would seem to be just fine?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check the status of a job every second, your application logic is wrong and I would strongly suggest that you consider other possible options. 
Could you post more info about what are you trying to achieve? There might be a better solution than job.